# scheduling timers in c#

Tags: c#

After launching my application i want to run my application sometimes later and not immediately after launching it.How do i do it?Can i accept the time when i want to run my application,through the comand line.Please help.Thanx in advance.

Regards,
Sanchaita sujit chakraborty

Comment: What is it your program "does" that you would want to run it at a later time... how about using a scheduler item.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand exactly what you want to accomplish but [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) is a library that you can use to schedule jobs in .NET.

Comment: Yeah given @Sacncheaita's comment on @Yoko Zunna, I think this is the best option. When I first read the question, I was why not use the OSes scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a scheduled task programmatically by spawning schtasks:
`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("schtasks", @"/create /tn mytask /tr C:\mypgm.exe /sc daily /st 18:55:00")`;
You can refer the schtasks doc to have more information on what you exactly need.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  [System.Threading.Timer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saba8ksx.aspx)  to schedule a method call

```
static void Main(string [] args)
{
    DateTime? startDate = null;
    if(args.length>1) 
    {
        DateTime.TryParse(args[0], out startDate);
    }
    if(startDate.HasValue && DateTime.Now<startDate.Value)
    {
        System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(StartProgram));
        timer.Change(startDate.Value.Substract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds, Timeout.Infinite);
    }
    else
        StartProgram();
}
private static void StartProgram()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Started");
    //rest of you code
}
```

Comment: This is how i am scheduling a particular method,but i want to schedule my application